# jstl page not found exception in logger

Tags: jsp, exception, jstl, jspinclude

I am including some JSP pages in one JSP page, whose names are in the keys of `Map` which I am iterating. In case if any of the JSP page is not found in my folder, then it throws exception, which I further handle in `<c:catch>`.

```
<c:set var="pagePath" value="/WEB-INF/pages/adminModule/"/>
<c:set var="jspName" value="${childItems.key}"/>
<c:set var="jspVar" value="${pagePath}organizationFilter${jspName}.jsp" />
<c:set var="jspVar" value="${fn:replace(jspVar,' ', '')}"/>

<c:catch var="e">
    <jsp:include page="${jspVar}"/>
</c:catch>

<c:if test="${!empty e}">
    <!-- ignore file doesnot exists-->
</c:if>
```

But the file not found exception is getting logged in server log. How can I stop that exception to come in server log?

Comment: I am including some jsp pages in one jsp page, whose names are in the keys of map which i am iterating, in case if any of the jsp page is not found in my folder then it throws exception which i further handling in  c:catch .But this file not found exception is getting logged in server log.

Comment: How can i stop that exception to come in server log